# Convert wpf datagrid to asp gridview

Tags: c#, gridview, datagrid

This c# code works fine in wpf framework.
Now I need this code in asp.net.
I am using GridView instead of DataGrid.
What changes do I have to do?

Here is my c# code:

```
DataRowView SelectedRowValue = (DataRowView)dataGrid1.SelectedValue;
byte[] ImageBytes = (byte[])SelectedRowValue.Row.ItemArray[1];
MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO Images (Image) VALUES (@ImageSource)", con);
cmd2.Parameters.Add("@ImageSource", MySqlDbType.Blob, ImageBytes.Length).Value = ImageBytes;
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can use Grid_RowUpdating Event using c#**

 `protected void oGridView_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)`
 
 `{`
    
     `GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];`
    
     `Label lblID = (Label)row.FindControl("Label1");`
    
     `TextBox txtImage = (TextBox)row.Cells[0].Controls[0];`
    
     `//........`
    
     `Then Update Command for MySQl which You are using//`
    
     `MySqlCommand oMySqlCommand = connection.CreateCommand();`
    
     `oMySqlCommand.CommandText = ""update detail set` 
     `Image='"+txtImage.Text+"'where id='"+userid+"'";`
    
     `connection.Open();`
    
     `command.ExecuteNonQuery();`
    `//.......`
    `etc//`
    
     `GridView1.EditIndex = -1;`

`}`